# Comment Deletion

Tags: discussion, comments

I am new to this site, but wanted to ask why it is suggested *to use comments sparingly*?

Are comments not to be used to flesh out details of the question?  On a **tiny scale**, they are used to respond to other users, which make the forum more engaging.

Just my two cents.

Comment: More specifics would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a moderator, I typically only suggest that when a comment thread starts getting very long -- when *many* users (particularly on a HNQ [hot network question]) start chiming in. That can make discussion difficult to follow.

*The reason we try to reduce reliance on comments:*

- It's important for additional details from the OP (e.g. "I'm in the United States" or "I'm writing from the perspective of a child, not a parent") to be part of the original question/answer, so other users find that relevant information quickly and easily. I *definitely* want to see users asking questions to help discover and refine those details, but also want to get them into the main body, not just the fine print.
- It doesn't help the OP for dozens of people to say "I think you're to blame as the parent" or "Wow, that WAS a dumb thing your kid did" or "why are you worried about this" -- or even positive alternatives "+1 for this amazing idea" (there is voting instead!)
- Particularly when many people are commenting, it becomes a massive challenge to follow individual conversation threads, even with the @ mentions.
- Part of StackExchange's fundamental concept is that voting enables better answers to move higher, and poorly written answers to be move lower. Comments can only get upvotes.

*The ways we try to reroute that enthusiasm to contribute:*

- Migrating extensive discussion to dedicated chatroom, or generally suggesting Parenting Chat as an alternative. People want to talk, that's super, and there's a place for that! (And we generally prefer migration over deletion, unless migration has already occurred and people are still failing to use chat...)
- If you've got an answer, write an answer! That brings the full voting and commenting toolset into play, and avoids well-meant and often very good advice being lost in the chatter.

It's a balancing act, and I'll grant that it isn't always perfectly performed. But we try :)

Comment: How many Mods on this site?

Comment: We've got three (myself, anongoodnurse, and Rory Alsop).

Comment: I agree with the line for a HNQ.  I just assumed that was the line here for all question.  My bad.  " I typically only suggest that when a comment thread starts getting very long -- when many users (particularly on a HNQ [hot network question]) start chiming in."  I think this is my first HNQ  :-)

Comment: It sometimes comes up on other questions too, but usually when two or three users start arguing -- which isn't productive, but also generally starts violating other rules like Be Nice. Congrats on the dubious honor of asking a HNQ :)

Comment: It's also important to note: This isn't a forum; it's a question/answer site. The purpose is not discussion but rather finding/giving solutions quickly.